# LibreOffice Calc SEARCH and FIND functions

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am trying to process some data in Calc. One of the steps involve finding if a certain string is part of one of the column. I tried using FIND and SEARCH functions. Both behave in the same way and I am not getting correct results.

E.g. Say I have following strings in Column A

```
NY
SF
LON
CAN
US
```

and am trying to put following formula in column C

```
=SEARCH("NY",A2)
```

The result is - cell C2 will have 1 (which is correct) but if the same formula is copied
to other cells in column C - it gives me "#VALUE!" error and I am unable to find out why ?

Any one has any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

The result `#VALUE!` is the default result if the search failes (see the [OpenOffice.org Calc documentation on the SEARCH function](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SEARCH_function)). Since all other strings don't contain "NY", that's the correct result for those cells.

I assume you mistook the resulting "1" as a "boolean" result, whereas a failed search would result "0". But this isn't the case. The [aforementioned documentation](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SEARCH_function) has some examples involving [ISNUMBER](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_ISNUMBER_function) and [ISERROR](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_ISERROR_function) to evaluate the result of the SEARCH function.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, if you want to search for a text in multiple rows/columns you need to give a range of cells, not just a single cell: `A2:A6`, or, better `$A$2:$A$6`.

Secondly, when you copy paste or translate one cell formula to another the $ counts as a constant coordinate. Let's say you put the formula in C2. That copied to C3 will give `=SEARCH("NY",A3)`. If you copied that to D2, the value would be `=SEARCH("NY",B2)`.

From what I read in Libre Office's help, FIND and SEARCH functions search for a text within another text, and I guess it matches the value in the first line of the range you give. So these functions don't do what you expected.

I did some research (trying different things), and it seems your best bet is using `MATCH` function to check if a value exists in a range of cells and `OFFSET` to get the value printed and not the index in the range.

```
=OFFSET($A$2; MATCH("SF";$A$2:$A$6; 0) - 1; 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

As @tohuwawohu mentioned, use the ISERROR (ISERR) function. When using SEARCH, it returns #VALUE! if the value is not found in the text. To accommodate for this in your logic use the following pattern:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(<str_to_find>, <str_to_search_in>)), <NOT_FOUND_do_something>, <IS_FOUND_do_something_else>)
```

This pattern of using ISERR can be applied to many other cases where a function returns an error. The only exception is #N/A where you must use the ISNA function.

Comment: Nice to see an answer to the question rather than debate about the semantic correctness of what's been implemented.

Comment: @gone - Agreed. So many people are bent on debating than answering. Still so much better than forums. I still remember the days before StackOverflow on google groups. Yikes!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the other answers explain why `ISNUMBER` is behaving this way, no one appers to have given you an actual real world example.

You can use `ISNUMBER` and `VALUE` hand in hand to *cast* your result to a number before you test using `ISNUMBER`.

For example, let's asume we have a string like `MDRLN4885B` in A1 and we want to know if the last charater is a non-number, in this case it's a "B".

`=ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A2, 1)))`

This would pretty much give you `FALSE` (or `TRUE` if it was a number) which you can then evaluate using `IF`, for example.